# White screen after pressing button to go to second page

Tags: android

So all I want to do is click the 'Sign up' button on my app and it takes me to the next page. I have made the second page and added a 'setOnclickListener' to the page I want but when I click on the button it takes me to another page that's white. I'm still new to Kotlin. There are no errors popping up that would effect it. Any ideas?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--logo-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image_view"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />


    <!--non interactive log in text-->

    <!--EmailAddress enter text-->
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textColorHint="#880E4F"
            tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize,TextContrastCheck" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColorHint="#4E342E"
            tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!--Login-->
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--register button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:onClick="mainActivity"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />




</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.gymapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var signUpButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.button)

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,RegistrationActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    fun mainActivity(view: View) {}

}
```

**RegistrationActivity.java**

```
package com.example.gymbuddies;

import android.app.Activity;

public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity {
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gymapp"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity android:name=".register" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="Registration">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_register.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".register">

    <!--logo-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image_view"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />


    <!--non interactive log in text-->

    <!--EmailAddress enter text-->
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>

    <!--email-->

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textColorHint="#4527A0"
            tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!--name-->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!--dob-->

    <!--password-->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





</LinearLayout>
```

**Register.kt**

```
package com.example.gymapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class Register : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var editTextEmail: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var editTextPassword: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var editName: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var buttonReg: Button
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var progressbar: ProgressBar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar)
        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.email)
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.password)
        editName = findViewById(R.id.name)
        buttonReg = findViewById(R.id.btn_register)

        buttonReg.setOnClickListener {


            progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val email = editTextEmail.text.toString()
            val password = editTextPassword.text.toString()
            editName.text.toString()
            // handle the button click event

            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Welcome!.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }


        }
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GymBuddies</string>
    <string name="password">Password</string>
    <string name="email_address">Email Address</string>
    <string name="type_your_name">Type your name</string>
    <string name="login">Login</string>
    <string name="email">Email</string>
    <string name="register">register</string>
    <string name="name">Name</string>
    <string name="sign_up">Sign up</string>
    <string name="todo">TODO</string>
</resources>
```

I've read through the code numerous times and I can't see anything conflicting.

Comment: Your button is opening `RegistrationActivity`, but it has no content because you haven't set any there. Indeed, even the class itself is empty. Are you sure you need `RegistrationActivity` at all? Did you mean to open `Register` instead? 'cause that's where you've set up the UI and Firebase and such. Did `RegistrationActivity` possibly get created accidentally, through some name mix-up, or maybe a fumbled refactoring?

Comment: So would it be a case of deleting the RegistrationActivity.java? completely and change any code with that class in other activity pages? And thank you for your fast response!

Comment: Maybe? I'm not really clear on your design. I would assume that you just ended up with an empty, extraneous class by mistake. Did you mean to rename `Register` to `RegistrationActivity` at some point? 'cause `Register` looks like it's what `RegistrationActivity` is supposed to be.